# LINQ Query for An object with 2 collections

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class `SearchOutput` which has a property `FilterGroups` that's an `IEnumerable<FilterGroup>`. In this instance, the `FilterGroups` is a list of two objects both holding the properties `Filters` and `Name`. Both objects hold different filters and a different name ("Brands" and "Color").

How would I get just one of those object's filters using LINQ?

Here is my code in the view:

```
@foreach(var filterGroup in Model.FilterGroups)
{
    foreach(var filter in filterGroup.Filters.Take(10))
    {
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="tickMark"></span><strong>@filter.Name<span>(@filter.ProductCount)</span></strong></a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

My classes:

```
public sealed class Filter
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
public sealed class FilterGroup
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> Filters { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class SearchOutput
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<FilterGroup> FilterGroups { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My controller's Action:

```
var searchOutput = new SearchOutput
{
    Layout = layout,
    ActionUrl = "/shop/{0}/{1}".FormatForInvariantCulture(input.Slug, input.Id),
    BreadboxSection = breadboxSection,
    Breadcrumbs = breadcrumbLinks,
    CurrentPage = page,
    FilterGroups = filterGroups,
    Name = isStorefront ? breadcrumbLinks.Last().Text : string.Empty,
    NextPageUrl = BuildNextPageUrl(products, input, page, selections, sort),
    PreviousPageUrl = BuildPreviousPageUrl(input, page, selections, sort),
    Products = productList,
    Selections = selections,
    SpotlightFilters = spotlightFilters,
    TotalPages = BuildTotalPages(products),
    UpcomingShows = UpcomingShows
};

if(isStorefront)
    return View("~/Views/" + RenderViewType + "/Store.cshtml", searchOutput);
else
    return View("~/Views/" + RenderViewType + "/Search.cshtml", searchOutput);
```

Comment: it would probably help to include the class you're passing as the `Model` to your view, but it's difficult to understand what you are asking

Comment: is `SearchOutput.FilterGroups` simply an `IEnumerable<FilterGroup>` ? if so, i don't see how it contains '2 collections both holding 2 properties Filters and Name'

Comment: then there are no '2 collections both holding 2 props' within `FilterGroups` .. so what you are currently doing looks correct

Comment: In the FilterGroups object you only have one collection. You have two properties (Filters, Names). I think you will need to clarify what your intention is a little more before anyone can help.

Comment: Are you saying Model.FilterGroups.Count would equal 2?

Comment: FilterGrouops has an array of 2 object [0] - "Brands", and [1] - "Color". How will I just get one of those objects? Each of those object has different collections...

Comment: Yes. Model.FilterGroup Count = 2. Exactly. (:

Answer (score 0):

rather than looping through foreach `FilterGroup` you can grab the `Filters` of the first `FilterGroup` with this:

```
@foreach(var filter in Model.FilterGroups.First(x => x.Name == "Brands").Filters.Take(10))
{
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="tickMark"></span><strong>@filter.Name<span>(@filter.ProductCount)</span></strong></a>
    </li>
}

@foreach(var filter in Model.FilterGroups.First(x => x.Name == "Color").Filters.Take(10))
{
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="tickMark"></span><strong>@filter.Name<span>(@filter.ProductCount)</span></strong></a>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: Actually how would I get the respective collection of each one?

Comment: i'll edit it to demonstrate, based on your comment about Brands and Color

Comment: I need to get Filters WHERE Filter.Name is equal to FilterGroup.Name

Comment: is `FilterGroup[0].Name="Brand"` and `FilterGroup[1].Name="Color"` or is just that any of the `FilterGroups` could contains a `Filter` with `Filter.Name="Brand"` ? hope that makes sense..